# Developing for WinCE, Windows Mobile and Windows Phone

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-phone, windows-ce

We are planning to choose the right developement technologie for an application that should run on Windows CE 5 and 6 and also on Windows Phone 7.

Please can you give me the choices I have.

Performance means a lot for us.

We prefer .net technlogies.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand the question.  Are you saying you have devices with CE 5.0, CE 6.0 and WinMo 6.x on them, you need to create an app for those devices and are asking for guidance on the development language to use?

If that's the case, you really only have two viable options:

1. Use the .NET Compact Framework.  You can develop in VB.NET or C#.  You will need Visual Studio 2008 Professional (or better).  Use CF 3.5 for the best performance (as opposed to CF 2.0).
2. Use native C/C++.  You will still need Studio 2008 Professional.

There is no such thing as "Windows Mobile 7" so I'm not certain if it's a typo and you meant 6, or if you meant Windows Phone 7.  There's a huge difference between the two and it would greatly affect the answer for that platform.

**EDIT**

Since you've thrown Windows Phone into the mix, things are more complex.  For windows Phone, you have only one option: managed code (yes it can be Silverlight or XNA, but it's still managed).  You also must use Studio 2012.

That means if you need to support all of those platforms, you need:

- Studio 2008 for the pre-Phone devices
- Studio 2012 for the Phone devices
- Managed code (C# or VB.NET) with very, very well separated business logic and UI logic

You will be able to re-use business logic across all platforms.  The UI code will be different on Phone than on the older platforms (and it's possible it will be different between CE and WinMo 6.x too).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually yes, I was need to create an app for those devices. And i mean Windows Phone 7, sorry.

Comment: Doeos silverlight can be run on Win CE devices please??

Answer (score 2):

For Windows CE 5 and 6 you can use C# .NET CF 3.5 or C++.

There is no Windows Mobile 7. For Windows Embedded Compact 7 (which is what I assume you meant), you must use [either Silverlight or C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200344.aspx).

If you meant Windows Phone 7, then you are strictly limited to Silverlight. There is no backwards compatibility with C++.

Comment: So there is no way to use metro style applications on those devices? right? Thank you for your answer. I appreciate.

Comment: You can make your interface look like anything you want in CE 5 and 6. But the style formerly known as metro is not built in to those platforms. You would have to draw it yourself.

Comment: "The style formerly known as Metro".  Classic!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you may want to go with a more general approach and do not bind the the unknown future of Windows Mobile, CE, Embedded Handheld.

There are some HTML5 based or Ruby based approaaches that will run on Windows Mobile, Blackberry, CE, Phone, iOS, Android and other devices. One example is Rhodes (RhoMobile) or, if HTML(5) based, something like PhoneGAP and Jo.

Or you go with a .NET approach as Xamarin offers .NET for non Windows Mobile devices as Android.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I find it interesting to try the multiplatform approach. But the question is;  does Rhodes  or PhoneGAP  or Jo or Mosync support Windows CE system??

Comment: And does it execute quickly without any slowness?

Comment: As mor frameworks or runtimes are involved between the 'code' and the native calls, the more you loose speed. Look at JAVA or .NET and compare that to native C code. A good alternative is to use HTML coding where the code runs (more or less) on the server and not on the client (except scripts etc). Rhodes runs on WinCE. The speed is not as good as with .NET so far I have seen. But that depends on the application you write.

Comment: I have one more question about using something like RhoMobile or PhoneGap is that I am going to use the barcodescanner of it but not a camera. the manufacturer provide c/c++ api to use that scanner. I am also going tu use database. Am I limited to use SQLite please? Is it still possible to continue looking in this path?

Comment: RhoMobile is partly open source and has been extended with Camera and Barcode Scanner support by Motorola for there (Symbol) handheld devices. You may also extend RhoMobile with native code wrappers to access special hardware. It is something like writing a JNI wrapper.

Comment: To your question about SQLite: yes, RhoMobile comes with SQLite and some usefull offline sync and other stuff. I dont think using SQLite is a restriction in there. As said, you can extend Rhodes yourself to add support for other databases or whatever you need.

Comment: I downloaded RhoMobile and my application seems that it need RhoElements which require to buy licenses per device. I didn't understand how would I pay for licenses butI think it is an inconvenient to use it especially if it require a license per device. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Developing applications in windows mobile and windows phone is entirely different. Windows mobile uses VS2008, but windows phone need VS2010 +.  Both code behind using c#/VB, but the GUI part in windows mobile is like windows form design, but windows phone use silverlight, its entirely different from windows mobile. So you need to develop 2 different application. one for windows mobile and one for windows phone.